# Duplicate resources error in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to establish connection to WAMP server, but I am getting this error

> The error message :
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   [string/id] C:\Grad\app\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml    [string/id] C:\Grad\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

This is it my styles.xml :

```
 <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

  </style>

 </resources>
```

dimens.xml :

```
  <resources>
  <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
  <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
  <string name="id" type="string">ID</string>
  </resources>
```

dimens.xml :

```
  <resources>
       <!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined in     res/values/dimens.xml
          (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of     available width. This
       would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp       respectively). -->
     <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>

    </resources>
```

strings.xml (w820 db)

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Grad</string>
<string name="send">Send</string>
<string name="id" type="string">ID</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Try not to  put string ids inside of dimens

Answer (score 4):

Its really duplicate, remove from dimen.xml

```
 dimens.xml :
 <string name="id" type="string">ID</string>

 strings.xml (w820 db)
 <string name="id" type="string">ID</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply just remove from dimens

- in dimens.xml remove

  `<string name="id" type="string">ID</string>`
- in strings.xml it just should be

  `<string name="my_id" type="string">ID</string>`

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is the same line of code somewhere else in the values folder xmls(dimens/styles).Remove the other one .Then it should work fine.